# Huawei Watch 2 LINEAR ACCELERATION

Tags: android, wear-os, accelerometer, watch, huawei-mobile-services

According to Android documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_motion.html

> linear acceleration = acceleration - acceleration due to gravity .
>   Which seems to work my 2 phones and LG Watch Urbane W150.

BUT, on my new Huawei Watch 2, linear acceleration still contains acceleration due to gravity. I'm running the same app on all devices, and only on Huawei Watch 2 I see this problem.

The command `adb shell dumpsys sensorservice` for **LG Watch Urban W150 give** this as output when the watch is lying on table:

```
Linear Acceleration: last 10 events
         1 (ts=24353.048620089, wall=17:28:40.031) -0.92, -0.15, 0.23, 
         2 (ts=24353.115270480, wall=17:28:40.086) -0.79, -0.17, 0.33, 
         3 (ts=24353.181920870, wall=17:28:40.146) -0.75, -0.14, 0.21,


MPU6515 Accelerometer: last 50 events
         1 (ts=93043.344428463, wall=12:33:30.392) -8.18, -2.35, 4.83, 
         2 (ts=93043.352240963, wall=12:33:30.392) -8.20, -2.35, 4.87, 
         3 (ts=93043.367865963, wall=12:33:30.392) -8.14, -2.35, 4.81,
```

As you see the x,y and z for LG watch is close to zero which is expected.

However, the same command but for **Huawei Watch 2** gives:

```
huawei Linear Acceleration Sensor: last 10 events
         1 (ts=31287.761652539, wall=17:31:07.258) -2.27, 6.58, 7.51, 
         2 (ts=31287.829730716, wall=17:31:07.325) -2.48, 6.41, 8.10, 
         3 (ts=31287.891682226, wall=17:31:07.387) -2.55, 6.60, 7.39,   


BMI160 3-axis Accelerometer: last 50 events
         1 (ts=100179.672482189, wall=12:39:19.258) 9.30, -3.46, 0.83, 
         2 (ts=100179.682469756, wall=12:39:19.258) 9.32, -3.46, 0.83, 
         3 (ts=100179.692457323, wall=12:39:19.258) 9.30, -3.47, 0.84,
```

And you see weird output for the linear acc sensor.

**Is it a bug in Huawei Watch 2?**

Comment: check if linear acceleration sensor returns a null or a proper value (exist). If it returns null then it doesn't exist on that watch. If there are an accelerometer and gyroscope, then it should work though.

Comment: Yes, it returns the sensor, but the output of this sensor is weird. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

All huawei equipment have this problem, maybe the SOC design issue or the driver's math is wrong.

Tested in huawei p40 mate20 p10, all got high bias result.